# Test Angular Reactive Forms using RxJS Marbles

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine, rxjs-marbles

Angular Component

```ts
public setupObservables() {
  this.formFieldChanged$ = this.formField
    .valueChanges
    .pipe(
        debounceTime(100),
        distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => a === b),
    )
}
```

Jasmine Test

```ts
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { marbles } from 'rxjs-marbles/jasmine';  
...

it('should update value on debounced formField change', marbles(m => {
  const values = { a: "1", b: "2", c: "3" };

  const fakeInputs = m.cold('a 200ms b 50ms c', values);
  const expected = m.cold('100ms a 250ms c', values);

  // works on stackblitz but otherwise gives TS2540 compiler error
  // cannot assign to a read-only property
  component.formField.valueChanges = fakeInputs; 
  component.setupObservables();

  m.expect(component.formFieldChanged$).toBeObservable(expected);
}));
```

[stackblitz.com example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-marble-tests?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.spec.ts)

The intent is to use marble tests to test `Observable` code in context with Angular reactive forms.

- Does this approach make sense?
- How to best mock the `valueChanges` of a `FormField` object?
- Is there a better way to structure these kind of tests?

Comment: Can you make a demo on stackblitz? In general, `valueChanges` is a Subject that emits values. By comparing it to `fakeInputs` you're not comparing individual emissions. What you need instead is `expectObservable` https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/testing/marble-testing.md

Comment: stackblitz demo added

Comment: `component.formField.valueChanges = fakeInputs` instead of the spyOn works.

Comment: yeah, so you've basically solved it yourself. You can make it even more simple by using just `const expected = '100ms a 500ms c';` and then pass `values` to `toBeObservable`.

Comment: Works on stackblitz but TS won't compile it due to `valueChanges` being a read-only property.

Comment: You can typecast it and then override `(component.formField as any).valueChanges = fakeInputs`.

Answer (score 6):

the question is - what you want to test. is it a unit test or an e2e test?
if it's a unit test - mock reactive forms, cover only your logic, then you don't have an issue with `valueChanges`, because it's mocked and you control it.

if it's an e2e test - you shouldn't reassign `valueChanges`. Nothing should be mocked / replaced, because it's an e2e test.

Nevertheless if you want to change `valueChanges` - use https://github.com/krzkaczor/ts-essentials#writable

```js
(Writable<typeof component.formField>component.formField).valueChanges = fakeInputs;
```

It will make the property type writable.

If it's a unit test, personally, I would vote to mock the reactive form, because in a unit test we need to test only our unit, its dependencies should be mocked / stubbed.

**Injection of parts we want to mock**

As an option you can move the form as a dependency of your component to providers in the component declarations.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl: './app-component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app-component.scss'],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: 'form',
            useFactory: () => new FormControl(),
        },
    ],
})
export class AppComponent {
    public formFieldChanged$: Observable<unknown>;

    constructor(@Inject('form') public readonly formField: FormControl) {
    }

    public setupObservables(): void {
        this.formFieldChanged$ = this.formField
            .valueChanges
            .pipe(
                debounceTime(100),
                distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => a === b),
            );
    }
}
```

Then you can simply inject a mock instead of it in a test.

```js
it('should update value on debounced formField change', marbles(m => {
    const values = { a: "1", b: "2", c: "3" };

    const fakeInputs = m.cold('a 200ms b 50ms c', values);
    const expected = m.cold('100ms a 250ms c', values);

    const formInput = {
        valueChanges: fakeInputs,
    };

    const component = new AppComponent(formInput as any as FormControl);

    component.setupObservables();
    m.expect(component.formFieldChanged$).toBeObservable(expected);
}));
```

Comment: My question was mainly about unit testing. To mock reactive forms I have to use `Writable` or is there a more straightforward way to do this?

Comment: yes, for unit testing you can simply mark it writable. If you want, the very right way would be to inject `this.formField` as a dependency to the component, then you could mock it without `Writable`. If you want I can update my answer to show an example.

Comment: Please do, that would be great for others looking for a complete solution.

Comment: updated, unfortunately, I don't know name of your component and used AppComponent instead.

Comment: It is not possible to use lambdas in decorators - `new FormControl()` would need to be in an exported function but otherwise looks like solid approach.

Comment: I think it's unsupported in very very old TS, we use it in 3.7 and 3.8 without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Using properties instead of fields is a much cleaner solution.

```
get formFieldChanged$() { return this._formFieldChanged$; }
private _formFieldChanged$: Observable<string>;

...
   
public setupObservables() {
  this._formFieldChanged$ = this.formField
    .valueChanges
    .pipe(
        debounceTime(100),
        distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => a === b),
    )
}
```

`spyOnProperty` does the magic here, `setupObservables()` is no longer needed:

```
it('should update value on debounced formField change', marbles(m => {
  const values = { a: "1", b: "2", c: "3" };

  const fakeInputs = m.cold('a 200ms b 50ms c', values);
  const expected = m.cold('100ms a 250ms c', values);

  spyOnProperty(component, 'formFieldChanged$').and.returnValue(fakeInputs);

  m.expect(component.formFieldChanged$).toBeObservable(expected);
}));
```